# Keyboard shorcut for "Go Into" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard, shortcut

I just wanted to know about, Is there any keyboard shortcut key available for the "Go Into" option into the eclipse 3.5 IDE. Any help will be really appreciate.

See below this screen shot if you can figure out the answer.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the shortcut yourself from `Preferences -> General -> Keys`. Search for Go Into and define your shortcut.
[image]